# Dynamic Collection Select in Rails using jQuery and AJAX

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a simple application, in which I allow users to create posts. In order to create a post, users need to select a category. I want to use a collection select to show the category. When a user selects a category, I need to show another collection select below it, which lists the sub categories within that category. All this happens in the posts/new page.

I tried to implement this using jQuery and AJAX, I only got to the point when I could find the id of the category from the first collection select, confirmed by showing an alert() box showing that id. But I have no idea how to make an AJAX POST to the server with that id, retrieve the subcategories, and then show the second collection select.

All the examples I have found in the web did not work for me. Can anyone provide me with a complete working code that can serve for my requirement? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, write a controller action which accepts a category ID as the parameter and renders it's subcategories in plain text in the format below:

```
<option value="1">First subcategory</option>
<option value="2">Second subcategory</option>
<option value="3">Third subcategory</option>
```

Next, write an AJAX request which is triggered when the category dropdown changes:

```
$('#category_dropdown').change(function() {
  var subcategory_url = "/get_subcategories?category_id=" + $(this).val();
  var subcategory_select = $(this).next('select');

  $.ajax({
    url: subcategory_url,
    success: function(data) {
      subcategory_select.html("<option selected=selected>Select Subcategory</option>" + data);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I was able to achieve this with something similar, i have that code in this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997476/show-ajax-based-elements-after-form-submit-error). Thanks for your help though.