# Show ajax based elements after form submit error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery, drop-down-menu

I have two select elements in my form, Category and Sub-category. At first, only the category select is shown. When the user makes a selection in the category select, an AJAX request is sent to the server and the subcategory select is shown. It works fine.

Now, when there is some error in the form submit, due to anything, missing some value that is required, or anything, I show the error message, but I cannot retain the same state of the select boxes, I see only the category select, with no value selected, i.e the initial state. Can anyone suggest me how I can preserve the state of these select elements?

Here's a code snippet from my new form:

```
    <div id="category-select">
    category <%= collection_select :post_category, :id, @categories, :id, :name, 
                                                options = {:prompt => "Select a category"} %>
    </div>
    <div id="sub-category-select">
    </div>
```

Here's my jQuery script that sends AJAX request when a selection is made on Category select:

```
$("#post_category_id").change(function() {
  var category_id = $('select#post_category_id :selected').val();
  if(category_id == "") category_id="0";
    $.get('/posts/update_sub_cat/' + category_id, function(data){
       $("#sub-category-select").html(data);
    })
  return false;
});
```

The AJAX request is made on the **update_sub_cat** action in the post_controller, which is shown below:

```
def update_sub_cat
  if params[:id].present?
    @sub_categories = Category.find_all_by_parent_id(params[:id])
  else
    @sub_categories = []
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
```

end

The AJAX request renders **update_sub_cat.js.erb** file, in which I have used some HMTL

```
sub-category <%= collection_select :post_sub_category, :id, @sub_categories, :id, :name, 
                                        options = {:prompt => "Select a sub-category"} %>
```

I know, I should not directly use HTML here, but rather use $('sub-category-select).append(...), but I got it working like this, and am planning to change it later.

This is all the code that is involved in this part of my program.

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: You're going to have to give more details.  Why can't you preserve the state of the select box?  How are you showing the error?  Etc... We are a programming community, show us code so we can help, otherwise there is not much we can do.

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought there would be some general trick for this, that's why I didn't provide the details, I have detailed my question now, please take a look. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the tag edits. Just shows my inexperience in stackoverflow use :)

Comment: No worries man.. power users tend to only look at questions with certain tags, so tagging is crucial to getting the right people to see your question.

Comment: :). I'm still waiting for solutions.

Comment: Are you saying that the `#post_category_id` is actually changing values when the AJAX gets kicked off?  For instance, you select a category from the `#post_category_id` select boxes, then AJAX gets sent, then `#post_category_id` changes??  If so, that's really strange since the code you're showing doesn't show that happening.

Comment: No, that's not it. As I said, at first, only the Category select box is seen, which says "Select a Category". Once the user selects a category, AJAX request is sent, which causes the sub-category select box to show, and user can select sub-category as well. However, if there is some error at the time of from submit, only the category select stays, and it says, "Select a category". Same happens when the page is refreshed. Basically, these elements are not part of the Rails Model, hence they do not preserve their state, and I'm seeking a means to preserve their state. Hope this clears things up.

Comment: Well, I was able to solve this problem. What I basically did was use session variables to save the state of these elements, and used AJAX get request to access these variables. Then, I used a hidden element at the top of my form, and at the end of load of the hidden element, I  made the AJAX call, and rendered my elements as per their state. Works beautifully now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem, and got the AJAX based element to maintain state. Here's my jQuery code:

```
$('#before_category_select').loadPage();

jQuery.fn.loadPage = function(){
if($("#new-post-area").length > 0){
    $.getJSON('/home/cat_select_state.json', function(data){
        $.get('/posts/update_sub_cat/' + data.cat_state, function(data1){
           $("#sub-category-select").html(data1);
        })
    });
   }
}
```

The controller action that I call to get the state of the select elements, which is stored as session variables at the time of page submit:

```
  def cat_select_state
    @cat_session = {:cat_state => session[:new_post_category], :sub_cat_state => session[:new_post_sub_category]}
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json {render :json => @cat_session}
    end
  end
```

And finally, I used a default values for the select boxes, which are stored as session variables. If the session variable is null, the default value is the prompt message for the select box.

```
<%= collection_select :post_category, :id, @categories, :id, :name, 
                                                options = {:prompt => "Select a category", :selected => session[:new_post_category]} %>
```

The HTML for sub-category select element is rendered in the javascript file update_sub_cat.js.erb.

```
sub-category <%= collection_select :post_sub_category, :id, @sub_categories, :id, :name, 
                                        options = {:prompt => "Select a sub-category"} %>
```

Please suggest if you have any more improvements.