# RoR: Super and Sub classing controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, polymorphism, subclass, superclass

So.. i have a method in a super controller that is the same as one in the sub controller.. all except for the redirect_to if the item doesn't save..

subclass method:

```
def create
some logic
respond_to do |format|
      if @template_object.save
        format.html { redirect_to({:controller=>:template_objects,:action=>:build,:id=>@template_object}) }
..
end
```

super method:

```
def create
some logic
respond_to do |format|
      if @template_object.save
        format.html { redirect_to({:controller=>:objects,:action=>:build,:id=>@object}) }
..
end
```

what is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have redirect_to in both super and sub class? In that case you might need to use a flag, like a session variable, to decide whether to use or skip redirect_to in the super class.

Devise uses a similar technique, for example, when we need to redirect_to a specific page after signing in using devise.

your super class

```
def method
   ...some logic...
   if !session[:redirect_var].nil?
      session.delete :redirect_var
      redirect_to ....
   end 
end
```

your sub class

```
def method
   session[:redirect_var] = 'skip_redirect' # or whatever, just create a session variable to use as a flag
   super
   ...some method...
   redirect_to ....
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The usual "object-oriented" approach to this is to create a method that both can call, then define it differently in each of them:

```
def redirect_to_completed_template(template_object)
  redirect_to(...)
end
```

The idea is to allow sub-classes to re-define only the portion of the functionality they require. This is why you will often see specific features broken out as functions even when what they do isn't especially complicated.

Comment: This seems to be a much elegant solution than mine. Would you please elaborate on how to implement? What do I pass into the ** redirect_to_completed_template**? I would like to learn to use this.

Comment: You pass in the object, which in your case appears to be either `@object` or `@template_object` depending on your example. The `redirect_to` line would then be one or the other accordingly.

Comment: Would you have something to say on [my question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997476/show-ajax-based-elements-after-form-submit-error) ? I'd be grateful if you could help me on this. Thanks.